# Maximizing $\left.\binom{N-40}{60-13}\middle/{\binom{N}{60}}\right.$

Tags: combinatorics, maximum-likelihood

I want to choose $N \in \mathbb{N}\geq 87$ to maximize 
$$\frac{\dbinom{N-40}{60-13}}{\dbinom{N}{60}} = \frac{(N-40)!60!(N-60)!}{47!(N-87)!N!}$$
which is equivalent to maximizing
$$\frac{(N-40)!(N-60)!}{(N-87)!N!}= \frac{(N-60)\cdots(N-86)}{N\cdots(N-39)}$$

Clearly the denominator "grows faster" than the numerator, so intuitively we want to make $N$ as small as possible, ie $N = 87$. Is there some way to show this rigorously, without taking derivatives?

Comment: Induction starting at $N = 87$

Comment: Thanks! Actually, trying induction (doing base case) made me realize that $N=87$ is not actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(N) = \frac{(N-60)\cdots(N-86)}{N\cdots(N-39)}$

$F(N+1) = \frac{(N-59)\cdots(N-85)}{(N+1)\cdots(N-40)}= \frac{N-59}{N+1}\frac{(N-60)\cdots(N-86)}{N\cdots(N-39)}\frac{N-40}{N-86}=\frac{N-59}{N+1}\frac{N-40}{N-86}F(N)$

As $N\ge87$ we just have to show $\frac{N-59}{N+1}\frac{N-40}{N-86}<1$

Which happens iff $(N-59)(N-40) < (N+1)(N- 86)$ iff $N \ge 175$.

So $F(N)$ is increasing from $86 \le N \le 174$ and decreasing on $175 \le N$.  So max will be at the last point it is increasing.  i.e. at $N = 174$.

Comment: I ended up getting $N = 175$, can you verify if this is correct?

Comment: We aren't solving for N.  Just showing F(N+1) < F (N).

Comment: @fleablood: But $\frac{(N-59)(N-40)}{(N+1)(N-80)}<1$ iff $N\ge 175$ (for integer $N$).

Comment: Replace N-50 with M and you get (M-9)(M-10)/(M+51)(M-36). By AM/GM that is less than 1.

Comment: But clearly it is not true by taking $N = 88$

Comment: Is that so?  I haven't set paper to pen  .  I could be wrong. But I really didn't think so.  If I'm wrong this would imply max is N =175.

Comment: Guess, you are right.

Comment: Yeah, I really should have done my work.  $\frac{N-59}{N+1}\frac{N-40}{N-86}<1 \iff \frac{N-59}{N-86}<\frac{N+1}{N-40}$  Clearly $N+1 > N-59$ but also $N-40 > N- 86$ so that alone is inconclusive.  $\frac{N-59}{N+1}\frac{N-40}{N-86}<1 \iff (N-59)(N-40) < (N+1)(N-86) \iff -99N + 2360 < -85N - 86 \iff 2446 < 14N \iff 174.7 < N$.  So ... yeah...  I should have had bells go off.

Comment: So the answer is N=174 as at N=175, F(175) < 1*F(174).